# Python make a list out of text file with one element on each line

Tags: python, list, file, text, element

I have a text file with a list of numbers (one on each line), is it possible to make a list out of that text file where there is one number on one line? I need this so that I can go through the list of numbers in pairs where I take the two first numbers first, 3rd and 4th after that and go through the whole file like that, untill there is no numbers left. Currently I get all of the numbers on the same line, but it gets tricky when I would need to use so other than the two first numbers.

```
list = []
file = open("doc.txt", "r")
for line in file:
list.append(line.strip())
```

EDIT: I have been trying to approach this with unnecessary complexity. I can just used the index of the list to make it work (I assume)

Comment: Pls show what exact output you desire? As you have a list at the end, there is no more concept of "lines". Btw, do you need the numbers as strings, or rther as floats or integers?

Comment: The output would need to be a list with for example [2 + 3 = 5], and string would be fine cause there is no need to use the outputs after that in any significant way

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to get the pairs:

```
with open("doc.txt", "r") as file:
    lst = [line.strip() for line in file]  # do not shadow built-in name `list`
pairs = [lst[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)]
```

Another (more elegant) way without an intermediate `list` (more space efficient) goes straight to the pairs using the involved iterators:

```
with open("doc.txt", "r") as file:
    nums = map(str.strip, file)
    nums = map(int, nums)  # if needed for calculations
    pairs = [*zip(nums, nums)]

for a, b in pairs:
    print(a + b)
    print(a - b)
    # ...
```

Comment: Do you reckon it would be easier to use these pairs or just the list index when trying to iterate through a list? I would need to be able to do some math calculations with two numbers that are given in the text file, and after every calculation it would need to move on to the next two numbers in the list/text file

Comment: Pairs are rather handy. I added the code for iterating over the pairs in a readable manner.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here.
After you build your list, split it in a new list where each element is a list of two elements, and after that itherate over new list.

```
list = []
file = open("doc.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    list.append(float(line.strip()))
pairs = [list[2*i:2*i+2] for i in range(0, len(list)/2)]
for x1,x2 in pairs:
    print("Calculate ({}, {})".format(x1, x2))
```

I've put in the text file the number 1...10 one per line, and the output is

```
Calculate (1.0, 2.0)
Calculate (3.0, 4.0)
Calculate (5.0, 6.0)
Calculate (7.0, 8.0)
Calculate (9.0, 10.0)
```

Assumption is that the text file has valid data: numbers and even number of lines.